# combobox - displaying multivalue numeric field

Tags: combobox, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a form which contains a multi-value enabled numeric field. I would like to display it on an xpage in a combobox when it has multiple value. However I get the error 500 message.

When I try to achieve the same thing with a multi-value text field the xpage got rendered.

What am i doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="doc" formName="test"
            action="editDocument">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:table>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label value="Label:" id="lb"
                    for="label1">
                </xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>             
                <xp:comboBox id="cbLabel" value="#{doc.label}">
                    <xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return doc.getItemValue("label")}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:selectItems>
                </xp:comboBox>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label value="Price:" id="pr"
                    for="price1">
                </xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:comboBox id="cbPrice" value="#{doc.price}">
                    <xp:selectItems>
                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return doc.getItemValue("price")}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:selectItems>
                </xp:comboBox>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>        
    </xp:table>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Check your log file in the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder to see the detailed error message. Use XPages Log File Reader if you aren't already :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xp:selectItems>` accepts String values only.

Convert your price's numbers in selectItems' value code into strings and
add a number or currency converter to your combobox.

As an alternative, you can create select items with a String label and a number value:

```
    <xp:selectItems>
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var items = new java.util.ArrayList();
            for (value in doc.getItemValue("price")) {
                var item = new javax.faces.model.SelectItem();
                item.setLabel(value.toString());
                item.setValue(value);
                items.add(item);
            }
            return items}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:selectItems>
```

Comment: thank you Knut. This works great. But when I try to save the choosen option back to the document it does not work. When I add a xp:messages control I get the message; Validation Error: Value is not valid. How should I reverse it when saving the document?